# Error while building with sdk 29 in qt creator

Tags: android, c++, qt, gradle

I'm working on a qt android application with Qt 6.2.4
, setting the sdk platform version to 29, I get the following errors

```
15:44:16: Running steps for project CameraErrorWorkOn...
15:44:16: Starting: "/home/linus/Qt/6.2.4/android_arm64_v8a/bin/qmake" /home/linus/Scrivania/qt/CameraErrorWorkOn/CameraErrorWorkOn/CameraErrorWorkOn.pro -spec android-clang CONFIG+=debug CONFIG+=qml_debug
15:44:16: The process "/home/linus/Qt/6.2.4/android_arm64_v8a/bin/qmake" exited normally.
15:44:16: Starting: "/home/linus/Android/Sdk/ndk/22.1.7171670/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/make" -f /home/linus/Scrivania/qt/CameraErrorWorkOn/build-CameraErrorWorkOn-Android_Qt_6_2_4_Clang_arm64_v8a-Debug/Makefile qmake_all
make: Nothing to be done for 'qmake_all'.
15:44:16: The process "/home/linus/Android/Sdk/ndk/22.1.7171670/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/make" exited normally.
15:44:16: Starting: "/home/linus/Android/Sdk/ndk/22.1.7171670/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/make" -j8
/home/linus/Qt/6.2.4/gcc_64/libexec/rcc -name qmake_resources qmake_resources.qrc -o qrc_qmake_resources.cpp
/home/linus/Android/Sdk/ndk/22.1.7171670/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang++ -c -target aarch64-linux-android23 -fno-limit-debug-info -fPIC -fstack-protector-strong -DANDROID -g -std=gnu++1z -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_QUICK_LIB -DQT_OPENGL_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_QMLMODELS_LIB -DQT_QML_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I../CameraErrorWorkOn -I. -I../../../../Qt/6.2.4/android_arm64_v8a/include -I../../../../Qt/6.2.4/android_arm64_v8a/include/QtQuick -I../../../../Qt/6.2.4/android_arm64_v8a/include/QtOpenGL -I../../../../Qt/6.2.4/android_arm64_v8a/include/QtGui -I../../../../Qt/6.2.4/android_arm64_v8a/include/QtQmlModels -I../../../../Qt/6.2.4/android_arm64_v8a/include/QtQml -I../../../../Qt/6.2.4/android_arm64_v8a/include/QtNetwork -I../../../../Qt/6.2.4/android_arm64_v8a/include/QtCore -I. -I../../../../Qt/6.2.4/android_arm64_v8a/mkspecs/android-clang -o qrc_qmake_resources.o qrc_qmake_resources.cpp
/home/linus/Android/Sdk/ndk/22.1.7171670/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang++ -target aarch64-linux-android23 -fno-limit-debug-info -Wl,-soname,libCameraErrorWorkOn_arm64-v8a.so -Wl,--build-id=sha1 -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-z,noexecstack -shared -o libCameraErrorWorkOn_arm64-v8a.so main.o qrc_qmake_resources.o   /home/linus/Qt/6.2.4/android_arm64_v8a/lib/libQt6Quick_arm64-v8a.so /home/linus/Qt/6.2.4/android_arm64_v8a/lib/libQt6OpenGL_arm64-v8a.so /home/linus/Qt/6.2.4/android_arm64_v8a/lib/libQt6Gui_arm64-v8a.so -lEGL /home/linus/Qt/6.2.4/android_arm64_v8a/lib/libQt6QmlModels_arm64-v8a.so /home/linus/Qt/6.2.4/android_arm64_v8a/lib/libQt6Qml_arm64-v8a.so /home/linus/Qt/6.2.4/android_arm64_v8a/lib/libQt6Network_arm64-v8a.so /home/linus/Qt/6.2.4/android_arm64_v8a/lib/libQt6Core_arm64-v8a.so -llog -pthread -lGLESv2   -llog -lz -lm -ldl -lc
15:44:16: The process "/home/linus/Android/Sdk/ndk/22.1.7171670/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/make" exited normally.
15:44:16: Removing directory /home/linus/Scrivania/qt/CameraErrorWorkOn/build-CameraErrorWorkOn-Android_Qt_6_2_4_Clang_arm64_v8a-Debug/android-build/assets
15:44:16: Removing directory /home/linus/Scrivania/qt/CameraErrorWorkOn/build-CameraErrorWorkOn-Android_Qt_6_2_4_Clang_arm64_v8a-Debug/android-build/libs
15:44:16: Starting: "/home/linus/Android/Sdk/ndk/22.1.7171670/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/make" INSTALL_ROOT=/home/linus/Scrivania/qt/CameraErrorWorkOn/build-CameraErrorWorkOn-Android_Qt_6_2_4_Clang_arm64_v8a-Debug/android-build install && cd /home/linus/Scrivania/qt/CameraErrorWorkOn/build-CameraErrorWorkOn-Android_Qt_6_2_4_Clang_arm64_v8a-Debug && /home/linus/Android/Sdk/ndk/22.1.7171670/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/make INSTALL_ROOT=/home/linus/Scrivania/qt/CameraErrorWorkOn/build-CameraErrorWorkOn-Android_Qt_6_2_4_Clang_arm64_v8a-Debug/android-build install
/home/linus/Qt/6.2.4/gcc_64/bin/qmake -install qinstall -exe libCameraErrorWorkOn_arm64-v8a.so /home/linus/Scrivania/qt/CameraErrorWorkOn/build-CameraErrorWorkOn-Android_Qt_6_2_4_Clang_arm64_v8a-Debug/android-build/libs/arm64-v8a/libCameraErrorWorkOn_arm64-v8a.so
/home/linus/Qt/6.2.4/gcc_64/bin/qmake -install qinstall -exe libCameraErrorWorkOn_arm64-v8a.so /home/linus/Scrivania/qt/CameraErrorWorkOn/build-CameraErrorWorkOn-Android_Qt_6_2_4_Clang_arm64_v8a-Debug/android-build/libs/arm64-v8a/libCameraErrorWorkOn_arm64-v8a.so
15:44:16: The process "/home/linus/Android/Sdk/ndk/22.1.7171670/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/make" exited normally.
15:44:16: Starting: "/home/linus/Qt/6.2.4/gcc_64/bin/androiddeployqt" --input /home/linus/Scrivania/qt/CameraErrorWorkOn/build-CameraErrorWorkOn-Android_Qt_6_2_4_Clang_arm64_v8a-Debug/android-CameraErrorWorkOn-deployment-settings.json --output /home/linus/Scrivania/qt/CameraErrorWorkOn/build-CameraErrorWorkOn-Android_Qt_6_2_4_Clang_arm64_v8a-Debug/android-build --android-platform android-29 --jdk /home/linus/java/jdk-11 --gradle
Generating Android Package
  Input file: /home/linus/Scrivania/qt/CameraErrorWorkOn/build-CameraErrorWorkOn-Android_Qt_6_2_4_Clang_arm64_v8a-Debug/android-CameraErrorWorkOn-deployment-settings.json
  Output directory: /home/linus/Scrivania/qt/CameraErrorWorkOn/build-CameraErrorWorkOn-Android_Qt_6_2_4_Clang_arm64_v8a-Debug/android-build/
  Application binary: CameraErrorWorkOn
  Android build platform: android-29
  Install to device: No
  -- Skipping /home/linus/Qt/6.2.4/android_arm64_v8a/plugins/iconengines/libplugins_iconengines_qsvgicon_arm64-v8a.so. It has unmet dependencies: lib/libQt6Svg_arm64-v8a.so.
  -- Skipping /home/linus/Qt/6.2.4/android_arm64_v8a/plugins/imageformats/libplugins_imageformats_qsvg_arm64-v8a.so. It has unmet dependencies: lib/libQt6Svg_arm64-v8a.so.
Warning: elemento non previsto (uri:"", local:"base-extension"). Gli elementi previsti sono <{}codename>,<{}layoutlib>,<{}api-level>
> Task :preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :checkDebugAarMetadata UP-TO-DATE
> Task :generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
> Task :extractDeepLinksDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :processDebugMainManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :processDebugManifestForPackage UP-TO-DATE
> Task :mergeDebugNativeDebugMetadata NO-SOURCE
> Task :mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :compileDebugShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :compressDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :checkDebugDuplicateClasses
> Task :mergeDebugJavaResource
> Task :mergeLibDexDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :mergeDebugNativeLibs UP-TO-DATE
> Task :stripDebugDebugSymbols UP-TO-DATE
> Task :validateSigningDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :writeDebugAppMetadata UP-TO-DATE
> Task :writeDebugSigningConfigVersions UP-TO-DATE
> Task :processDebugResources FAILED
> Task :desugarDebugFileDependencies

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$TaskAction
   > Android resource linking failed
     ERROR:/home/linus/Scrivania/qt/CameraErrorWorkOn/build-CameraErrorWorkOn-Android_Qt_6_2_4_Clang_arm64_v8a-Debug/android-build/build/intermediates/packaged_manifests/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:26: AAPT: error: attribute android:allowNativeHeapPointerTagging not found.
         

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

24 actionable tasks: 4 executed, 20 up-to-date
BUILD FAILED in 2s
Building the android package failed!
  -- For more information, run this command with --verbose.
15:44:20: The process "/home/linus/Qt/6.2.4/gcc_64/bin/androiddeployqt" exited with code 14.
Error while building/deploying project CameraErrorWorkOn (kit: Android Qt 6.2.4 Clang arm64-v8a)
When executing step "Build Android APK"
```

My building kit is
[image]

The code is the default code of QQuickApplication template, I couldn t figure out what's going on, if anybody is able to help me I'd really appreciate, thank you in advance

Comment: `android:allowNativeHeapPointerTagging` is only available for `targetSdkLevel >= 30` see (at the bottom) https://source.android.com/devices/tech/debug/tagged-pointers

Comment: Ok but I do not create my AndroidManifest.xml file because qt creator does it for me, but I don't know how to make it create a compatible AndroidManifest.xml for sdk 29